# Hibernate Search, Infinispan, amazon s3 configuration.

Tags: hibernate, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hibernate-search, infinispan

I'm trying to figure out how to configure hibernate-search to work with inifispan and amazon s3. I can't seem to find much documentation out there providing examples on how to do it. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

I found the following documentation, however it seems very sparse.

http://infinispan.org/docs/cachestores/cloud/

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.2/reference/en-US/html/search-configuration.html#infinispan-directories

Answer (score 2):

The most important detail is to change the lookup protocol, as you can't do UDP multicast on AWS.
See:
http://blog.infinispan.org/2010/05/infinispan-ec2-demo.html
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Running+Infinispan+on+Amazon+Web+Services